# nzsql command in ssis

Tags: unix, ssis, netezza, nzsql

Is it possible to connect SSIS to an uniX server?

How can run an nzsql command from SSIS in an unix server to invoke another netezza server.

```
SSIS --> UNIX --> NZSQL --> NETEZZA server
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you planning to deploy and execute SSIS packages on a UNIX machine?

If you are asking only about connecting:
SSIS supports ODBC and Oledb types of database connections. So you may create Data Flow Task and then inside of it use ODBC Source (or Destination) [image]

Answer (score 0):

The way I invoke a LINUX (UNIX) from SSIS is using PLINK.EXE

I code my sequence that needs to perform via bash script (.sh) and invoke the bash script from SSIS using plink.exe (more info on how to use plink is given here)

https://www.ssh.com/ssh/putty/putty-manuals/0.68/Chapter7.html

You can also pass parameters from SSIS to bash (using SSIS expressions)